# How to get a NOTAM on a Restricted Area?

Tags: faa, notam, special-use-airspace

Is there any online service to get restricted area NOTAMS?

For example how can I get NOTAMs related to R-2503-D (intermittent by NOTAM 24 Hrs in advance) on Los Angeles Sectional chart?

I found this [website](https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/) but I am not sure how to find by restricted area name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For [SUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_use_airspace) NOTAMs, you can find it via [sua.faa.gov](https://sua.faa.gov), in either map or text format.

If an SUA on a chart has defined hours, stick to those.

Example after downloading the text data:

[image]

Map example (layer control is useful):

[image]

Color indicates if active or scheduled and how far in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Restricted areas are controlled by the appropriate controlling agencies.  They will be listed either next to the area on a WAC or SAC chart, on in the chart sideliners.  I don't think NOTAMS will be utilized for this information.

Comment: If you look at the legend it actually mentions "intermittent by NOTAM 24 Hrs in advance"